# HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.HashMap in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to return a json using HashMap like this in a method in the controller

```
//list all users
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>> handleRequest() throws Exception{
        List<User> users = userService.list();          
        Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        message.put("severity", "info");
        message.put("user", users);
        message.put("summary", "Not successfully.");
        message.put("code", 200);

        Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        json.put("success", true);
        json.put("message", message);

        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>>(message,HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

When I hit this method in PostMan I get this error

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.HashMap
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:226)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:180)
org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

This is how I have setuped the Application

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.fyt.fyt")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationContextConfig {


    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fyt");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {

        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        factoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(User.class);
        return factoryBean;

    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDao userDao() {
        return new UserDaoImpl();
    }
}
```

The error says, it cannot convert the list to httpmessges so do I need to any any converters or something like that? What am I missing something?

Comment: This looks like you don't have the converters set up suitably. You'll need to share more information about your Spring setup. Is this a legacy application you're adding JSON to, or a modern Spring Boot project?

Comment: This is a legacy application, I have edited the question, please check

Comment: Did you try this solution?

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28893796/returning-a-simple-map-structure-from-spring-mvc-controller-to-ajax)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provide **@RestController** in Controller class level other wise provide **@ResponseBody** in method level.
Make sure that all jackson related jars are there in class path.

Add jackson related  dependencies in to your pom.xml

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user",method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>> handleRequest() throws Exception{
        List<User> users = userService.list();          
        Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        message.put("severity", "info");
        message.put("user", users);
        message.put("summary", "Not successfully.");
        message.put("code", 200);

        Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        json.put("success", true);
        json.put("message", message);

        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>>(message,HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Sample pom dependencies for jackson .

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: It was because of the dependencies so adding the dependencies solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

For someone coming with similar problem:

This can happen if you are returning an object of a class that has no Getter and Setter methods.

For ex:
if you have the following setup

```
public class Employee {
    private int code;
    private String name;
}
```

And using it in some method as such :

```
@GetMapping("")
public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployee(@RequestParam("id") Integer id) {
    Employee employee;
    /* CODE. . . 
                */
    return new ResponseEntity<>(employee, HttpStatus.OK);
 }
```

You might get an error saying

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class com.dummy.springWeb.ExceptionHandler.Employee

To resolve, just add getters and setters to the employee class and it will solve the problem!

Comment: saved my life, and for thoes who uses lombok, simply add @Data to your entry

Answer (score 1):

I think you need custom httpmessageconvertor for this.
**add Dependency**

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
     <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

if this not works then try to configure custom configuration for MappingJackson to HttpMessage Convertor in your Configuration File.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar error `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList`, even with all the jackson dependencies properly added in my gradle file. My spring version was `Spring 5.2.3.RELEASE`. I had all the getters and setters added in the objects that are being added in the collection. I tried with several version of `jackson-databind` nothing helped. Finally it was one line in my `spring-config.xml`

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Origial stackoverflow question that helped me [How to return JSON data from spring Controller using @ResponseBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905917)

All of this started, when I have to change my application from spring-boot to plain vanilla spring-mvc application. This was required as the SonaType nexus library scan was reporting vulnerabilities in the sub dependencies of Spring boot libraries

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return a Map like this and user @RestController annotation on top of your class:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String,Object> handleRequest() throws Exception{
        List<User> users = userService.list();          
        Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        message.put("severity", "info");
        message.put("user", users);
        message.put("summary", "Not successfully.");
        message.put("code", 200);

        Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        json.put("success", true);
        json.put("message", message);

        message.putAll(json);
        return message;
    }
```

Comment: Does your User class have setter and getters method ?

Comment: Yes, it has getters and setters

Comment: Please wrap the code in try catch and post the full stack trace of error.

Comment: I have added the full stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

People with similar errors and most things correct, try to add this header in the API request! I faced this too

`Accept : application/json` (Or whichever media your response is producing)