# When is manual mapping using Jackson's ObjectMapper needed for converting pojo to json in Spring Rest's @ResponseBody annotated controller method?

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-rest, jackson2

I want to know what is the rule followed by MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to convert the object (returned from controller method annotated by `@ResponseBody`) to a json? In some situations I see that just having Jackson2 on classpath (pom.xml) is enough and the controller simply returns back its object e.g. String or a collection e.g. `List<Employee>` successfully to browser in json format. But, in other cases I have seen that the solution asks me to use an `ObjectMapper` and use method `writeValueAsString` to get a string and return that as a response, example `HashMap`s! Are there some implicit rules which MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter uses to decide if it is able to do the conversion on its own or I need to manually do it using `Objectmapper` ? If I have a pojo object, which internally has few `String` fields, would I still need to use ObjectMapper etc? If not then would I need it if my pojo class has fields like , some `List<CustomObject>` and some `HashMap`s?
For example : [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905917/how-to-return-json-data-from-spring-controller-using-responsebody) does not use any ObjectMapper to convert `List<Company>` to json in controller method. But, [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28893796/returning-a-simple-map-structure-from-spring-mvc-controller-to-ajax) needs an `ObjectMapper` and `writeValueAsString` ? plus, it's return type now is `String` instead of a `HashMap`!

Answer (score 0):

If you use @RestController and you have jackson in the class path everything will be handled OK. see https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ and https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/014-post-json-to-spring-rest-webservice/

Comment: So it would work for any kind of return type ? Complex POJO object with Strings/Lists/Maps? And no need to use `ObjectMapper` ? So when would I need to use an `ObjectMapper` in a controller method? p.s. This link also corroborates what you said, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284025/spring-mvc-is-it-possible-to-return-a-mapstring-object-dynamically-converted

Comment: Very very rarely will you have to do anything, Jackson and @RestController is all you need.

Comment: So what could be a use case of using `ObjectMapper` & 'writeValueAsString' in a `@Controller` ?

Comment: If in the very rare case that Jackson can't handle the de-serialization, then you should define a JsonDeserializer (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724693/jackson-deserialize-object-with-list-of-springs-interface/35726158#35726158)  and assign it to the POJO, you never do it in the Controller.  The Controller should return a ResponseEntity.